# How do I display a name associated with a certain variable?...Please clarify this part

Tags: c++, stack

```
#include &lt;iostream>
#include &lt;stack>
#include &lt;string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    double gpa;
    double high = 0;

    stack&lt;string>names;

    for (int i=0; i&lt;7; i++)
    {
        cout &lt;&lt; " Enter student's name and gpa " &lt;&lt; endl;
        cin >> gpa ;
        cin >> name ;
    }

    { 
        if (gpa > high)
        {
            high = gpa;
            names.push(name);
        }
        else if (gpa=high)
        {
            high = gpa;
            names.push(name);
        }
    }

    cout << "Highest gpa is"<< high << "Names with highest gpa "<< ??? <<< endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

There's this list of names and with GPAs to these names, 7 to be exact. I have the algorithm to get the highest GPA and I know there's some sort of while loop condition to use in order to get the names of the persons with the highest GPA.

From the question 2 people have the same highest GPA... How will I display both these names with the highest GPA separately? I cant seem to get that part where I could associate the name with the GPA.

Help would be much appreciated.

Edited: Is there an easier method of using a while loop somewhere within that for loop in my code? Where I use the `if (gpa < high)` statement, am I missing something to get the names with the highest GPA?

Comment: Your condition in the `else if` is broken.

Comment: What do you mean broken?it means if the gpas are equal to the highest gpa i wanted to display the names with that gpa..but is there any other right code?

Comment: @Surya: He's pointing out that what you have is an assignment instead of a comparison.

Comment: @Surya, `else if (gpa=high)` should be `else if (gpa == high)`

Comment: @Surya, `gpa = high` is for `assignment` and not `comparison`.

Comment: what should be there after "Name with highest gpa"<< ??? ...

Comment: @Devendra: Code should be indented with four spaces.  You don't need to HTML-escape it.

Comment: @Surya: If you can't take the time to at least try to spell things right, people won't take much time to help you.

Comment: @Surya - I've corrected the typographical errors that resulted in quite a few flags. Please construct sentences as though you were communicating with your professional peers, not as if you were sending a text message.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Data {
 std::string name;
 int gpa;
};
```

then use a `std::priority_queue<Data>` to store it ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/ ) (and make sure to create a comparison operator)

Also use == for equality not = (which is assignment)

Comment: I want to do this without the use of linked lists

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name;
    double gpa;
    double high = 0;
    stack<string>names;
    for (int i=0;i<7;i++) {
        cout << " Enter student's name and gpa " <<endl;
        cin >> gpa;
        cin >> name;
        if (gpa > high) {
            high = gpa;
            names.clear();
            names.push(name);
        }
        else if (gpa == high) {
            names.push(name);
        }
    }
    cout << "Highest gpa is "<< high << " held by:" << endl;
    for (stack<string>::const_iterator it(names.begin()); it != names.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there some easier code that im missing...over at the if (gpa < high) or the if (gpa==high) statements??somewhere around there ..am i missing some sort of while loop to get the names?

Comment: Matt: I'd replace the final `for` loop with: `std::copy(names.begin(), names.end(), std::ostream_iterator<string>(std::cout, "\n"));`.